# Is there an easy way to make a relly old web page, that has hard coded values and used a lot of tables for formatting, responsive with a media query?

Tags: html, css

As the title says pretty much. I have a lot of hard coded widths and the whole thing is using tables to position the items. Is there an easier way to make it mobile friendly, other than going trough the whole code changing things? Preferably with just css, no javascript.

Comment: yes, recode it with media queries

Comment: When you say 'hard coded' is that in style atrributes or is it in stylesheets? Perhaps you could give us an example of the sort of thing that needs altering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure,
With css+media queries you can re-style all the table/tr/th/td elements.

if you want a short example.
just try to apply this style to your website

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
       tr {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
       }
    }
</style>
```

And reducing the windows,
you'll see that all rows will become flexible

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).